# Is there a way to reflect the changes done in a java project(in Intellij) while debugging/not debugging without having to rebuild the project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project that takes quite sometime to build and it becomes difficult to rebuild again and again after testing if I do some fix. I was wondering if there was a way in which I could do the hot fix test it without having to rebuild whole module. I am using Intellij. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging you can change the values with Intellij and apply them before the line is executed without the need to recompile. Here is the official documentation from [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluate-expression.html).

While not debugging it's kinda impossible unless you use a plugin, for example, you can hot reload using [JRebel](https://www.jrebel.com/products/jrebel/learn)

Comment: I have to add a line of code not the value. Is there a way to it?

Comment: No without a plugin like JRebel.